# TypeScript How to make String Union Type to a concrete Obnject Type?

Tags: typescript, generics, covariance, union-types

how can i implement this:

```
type ActionNames = 'init' | 'reset';

type UnionToObj<U> = {/* TODO HERE */}

type Result = UnionToObj<ActionNames>;
// expect type Result to be `{ init: any, reset: any }`
```

i had written a implementation, but it not work correctly, it meets the union extends covariance problem:

```
type UnionToObj<U> = U extends string ? { [K in U]: any } : never;
type Result = UnionToObj<'init' | 'reset'>;
// expecting the type Result to be `{ init: any, reset: any }`
// but i got a union object: `{ init: any } | { reset: any }`
// how do i resolve it ?
```

main problem:

1. string union type to object type
2. union's covariance in ts extends clause.

Comment: I don't see "covariance" being a factor here at all, although maybe I'm just not understanding how you're using the term in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a straightforward [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types):

```
type UnionToObj<U extends PropertyKey> = { [K in U]: any }

type Result = UnionToObj<ActionNames>;
/* type Result = {
    init: any;
    reset: any;
} */
```

Here we are [constraining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) `U` to be key-like instead of checking it via a conditional type.  If you really want to do it that way, you can, with a solution like this:

```
type UnionToObj<U> = [U] extends [PropertyKey] ? { [K in U]: any } : never;
```

The difference between this and your version is that your version is unintentionally a [*distributive* conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).  Since you don't want union inputs to become union outputs, you need to prevent conditional type distribution by not having `U extends ...` directly with a bare type parameter in the checked position.  Wrapping the checked type in a one-tuple (`[U] extends ...`) is enough to turn off union distribution.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHYDkCGBbCBnKAXigHJFVFgSoAfUgJ3wioG4BYAKE9EigFUKaACrIA8gCMAVgB4+UCAA9gEVABMCABXrJI9UAGkIIAHxEoAbygBtfVHL8AugC4omVCCgBfTt3DQASvgArgA2wGYCKKgiEjLwSGhYuHjG7BwA9ABUUDwBwWFm5pxQJXYUwC5uIGmlUIx4zJXuaZ5Qmek+XBy5-ILRYlIATLKmxFZ8DvJKKurWWjoQeiCGIJMA-BbWtvYTTR6tLqgQAG6Lab68gXihwIMRfTFD0vFRSfipnFk5flBXN3fEIocWrkSh7GqleqNVzNTitdpAA)